# How to trap the linux user log off signal in the Java daemon process?

Tags: java, linux, signals

I am working on a linux daemon process which is written by Java. If the current user log out, I need to trap the signal and post some message to the remote server. How to catch the current user log out signal in the Java code? Can the signal SIGHUP work? Anybody can give some clues?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you want to handle SIGQUIT? If the user closes quit his sessioin with exit? The my solution below will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could register a signal handler to handle SIGHUP.

```
import sun.misc.Signal;
import sun.misc.SignalHandler;

public class SigHupDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // you can also register for "TERM" - SIGTERM
    Signal.handle(new Signal("HUP"), new SignalHandler () {
      public void handle(Signal sig) {
        System.out.println("got a SIGHUP");
        // do what you want to do in such case
        // also include to end your daemon
      }
    });

    for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      System.out.print('.');
    }
  }
}
```

To test you can run it that way

- in session 1: run the demo `java SigHupDemo`
- in session 2: kill -s HUP $PID_OF_SIGHUPDEMO

The output in session 1 will be something like this after you sent a SIGHUP

```
....got a SIGHUP
...
```

The demo will only print `got a SIGHUP` in case the JVM receives a `SIGHUP`. As mentioned in the code you need to implement your own proper handling there.